# Do lapped cars need to finish the remaining laps?

Tags: formula-1

Consider that the leading car has finished the race, and there are a few cars that have been lapped. Do those drivers need to finish the remaining laps, or do they just need to finish the current lap that they're on?

For example, the Sao Paulo GP has 71 laps. Consider a driver that's been lapped twice (currently on lap 69). So, does the lapped driver need to finish  all 71 laps, or just 69 laps?

Comment: Could you explain why you are asking this question while at the same time providing the [exact answer to the question here](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/27955)? While Stack Exchange supports self-answered questions, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 4):

They do not finish any laps that they are down.  The following  [sporting regulations](https://www.fia.com/sites/default/files/formula_1_-_sporting_regulations_-_2022_-_iss_6_-_2022-04-29.pdf) are relevant:

> 59.1.   A chequered flag will be the end-of-session signal and will be shown at the Line as soon as the leading car has covered the full
> distance in accordance with Article 5.3.

> 59.3 After receiving the end-of-session signal all cars must proceed on the circuit directly to the parc fermé without any unnecessary
> delay, without receiving any object whatsoever and without any
> assistance (except that of the marshals if necessary).

> 62.1 The car placed first will be the one having covered the scheduled distance in the shortest time, or, where appropriate, passed the Line
> in the lead at the end of two (2) hours (or more under Article 5.4).
> All cars will be classified taking into account **the number of complete
> laps they have covered**, and for those which have completed the same
> number of laps, the order in which they crossed the Line.

So under most races the leader brings out the checkered flag at the lap limit and all cars stop racing once they reach the flag.

Going back to [Brazil 2021](https://www.formula1.com/en/results.html/2021/races/1104/brazil/race-result.html), we can see that only six cars finished on the lead lap.  The remainder are shown without a time and just the fact that they finished more than a lap back.  They have a lap count less than the leader in the official classifications.  That year the two Haas drivers indeed finished 2 laps back and completed only 69 laps.